# WxPython Changing a button (bitmap) on a button panel

Tags: wxpython

Created my first button panel using `wx.lib.agw.buttonpanel`. 
It has numerous buttons, And i need to change a specific button's image on a specific event , How can i do that ? 
Currently i recreate the whole panel, looking for a better way.

Here how i create them :

```
for count, png in enumerate(self.pngs):
    shortHelp = short_help[count]
    kind = wx.ITEM_NORMAL
    longHelp = long_help[count]
    btn = bp.ButtonInfo(self.titleBar, wx.NewId(),
                                png[0], kind=kind,
                                shortHelp=shortHelp)

     self.titleBar.AddButton(btn)
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, OnButtonFunc[count], id=btn.GetId())
     self.titleBar.AddSeparator()
```

Comment: accepted? sorry , how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a normal `wx.BitmapButton` you can use the `event` to change the image. I don't know if you will get the same mileage with a `wx.lib.agw.buttonpanel`.

You will need to store the image to swap to, against the `Id` of the button, then use the event to swap the image.

```
def MyButtonFunction(self, event):
    ButtonId = event.GetId()
    #Map the Id to the image here#
    event.GetEventObject().SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('/path/to/button/image/swap.png'))
```